# What is a clean way to replace a wall of if-statements that only return false?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm writing a simple email verifier. I have a working solution, but it uses a wall of if-statements that all just return false. Is there a cleaner way or a design pattern for this kind of problem? (I only included the code I want to simplify)

```
if (prefix.length() == 0 || domain.length() == 0 || topLevelDomain.length() < 2) {  // if prefix or domain length == 0, or topLevelDomain < 2
    return false;
} else if (!isBuiltFrom(prefix, alpha + digit + special)) {  // if any char in prefix is not (a-z), (0-9), '_', '.' or '-' return false
    return false;
} else if (!isBuiltFrom(domain, alpha + digit + "-")) {  // if any char in domain is not (a-z), (0-9), or '-' return false
    return false;
} else if (!isBuiltFrom(topLevelDomain, alpha)) {  // if any char in topLevelDomain is not (a-z) return false
    return false;
} else if (special.contains("" + prefix.charAt(0))) {  // if prefix leading special char return false
    return false;
} else if (special.contains("" + email.charAt(prefixIndex - 1))) {  // if prefix trailing special char return false
    return false;
} else if (special.contains("" + domain.charAt(0))) {  // if domain leading special char return false
    return false;
} else if (special.contains("" + email.charAt(domainIndex - 1))) {  // if domain trailing special char return false
    return false;
}
```

return true;

Comment: A trivial improvement would be to change all the `else if` to `if`.

Answer (score 2):

```c
if (A) {
    return false;
} else if (B) {
    return false;
} else if (C) {
    return false;
} else if (D) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

Convert to:

```c
return !A && !B && !C && !D;
```

Answer (score 1):

The are various ways to make your code easier to read or maintain.

You could define an interface Validator, with a simple method isValid() for example. Then each check becomes its own little class. Then you put one instance of each class into a list, and checking means to go through that list to invoke the check method. This means more code, with plenty of boilerplate, but it allows for very simple adding of new checks: just another class, and adding another object to that list. You don't have to touch the looping part ever again.

Another idea: simple put each of your checks into a distinct helper method that has a clear telling name. That would allow you to completely drop all these comments. You see instead of writing

```
// if condition X return false 
if whatever X... return false
```

You go

```
if isX(.....) return false
```

That doesn't change the overall structure much, but the resulting code should be much easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I don't think rewriting will improve the readability.   Except that maybe readability would be improved by changing the comments to explain what the tests *mean*.

<sup>(Many of the comments in your example are more-or-less literal translations of the test expression.  That kind of comment is redundant ... assuming that the person examining your code can *read* Java.)</sup>

Now, if the individual tests were more complicated, or they were used in other places in the code base, then refactoring the tests as predicate methods would help.  And more so if a *group* of those tests was used in other places, and you factored out the common group.

---

But it boils down to this.  Which of these do >>you<< think is easier to read?

```
if (prefix.length() == 0) return false;
```

versus

```
if (isPrefixEmpty(prefix)) return false;
```

where the declaration

```
boolean isEmptyPrefix(String prefix) {
    return prefix.length() == 0;
}
```

could be 50 lines away, or in a different file.

Consider that to read the second one, you need to *either* KNOW that `isPrefixEmpty` is doing the appropriate test (because you read it before and you remember what it does) *or* you need to look at the method definition.  If you have to (find and) look at the definition, that interrupts the "flow" of your reading of the code.  If you just *assume* `isPrefixEmpty` does what you think it does, then you risk misreading the code.

---

Bottom line:  refactoring can be good ... and it can be bad.  You have to consider what the results are going to look like.  And the same applies to design patterns.

A "wall of `if` tests" might be aesthetically dissatisfying, but aesthetics is not the best criteria for judging code.  Other things are more important ... for a professional programmer doing their job.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I think you can simplify your if-else based on the function you check.
like this:

```
if (prefix.length() == 0 || domain.length() == 0 || topLevelDomain.length() < 2) {  
   return false;
}else if(!isBuiltFrom((prefix, alpha + digit + special) || (domain, alpha + digit + "-") || (topLevelDomain, alpha)){
   return false;
}else if(special.contains(("" + prefix.charAt(0)) || ("" + email.charAt(prefixIndex - 1)) || ("" + domain.charAt(0)) || ("" + email.charAt(domainIndex - 1))){
   return false;
}
```